# Encrypt/Decrypt text using existing key pair

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

This has been extremely confusing to me.  I have a process where I generate a public/private key pair using PHP.  This is the code where I do that:

```
$config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);

// Create the private and public key
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
```

And here is an example of the generated output:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA1ufdaaaDQuWPuBlw8Vce
>   WeGwdL3KhrC/YzgWi8oP72bQ2ZzgxzNcXHdmWGfXax4EBlWwIPBbTSNboi6urieb
>   bPNIS/ei/AjGBKO/yJ2iDkfnxmy6xBxwpunqeq2TjEDDNXb2Y0g896gIjfwN8FZk
>   olLspoFks5ipAxdYLNlWR5stgxWeEXC2gpAPLaP00d3Xg/Qhsm2fUBvlJHQReiS1
>   Mwyajg0EV72U3YpP0OK19z0YLBFRhaUbnE+Mx6TSnB9XqaWe4GKsBNSO06Lz4N9j
>   k7Sg16DXpueKHo8pDZwuN2qbIG3fGc3ibNMR2U6lux218BGTIgGdvoAar1E3cOF1
>   VmLI3aDS/EVejzDs3gkG1rxcrbCFajnWe5Yl1J+nXefFBedr2FLx6ChSPZFV1x3P
>   DUmR1hb/NDsLHwnj7qQqqhtgfPdFql4EjGFGUvYgid1K0u/8B6Vqk0k9JKU5nrN5
>   d1e3H7qJm/kbBoHNsI/0gbuUyRKTIpxU5b9ex51WpA80FBMC/Ao6DeWLNu59W134
>   YGu5kfI1qFI0w5xUsA3IU91Ak2tHYEzzjnIz0rVMoJezLbtxcv26e5gMDjuQN//d
>   UM/Qe6Akck382yYgdrivgUjxB3A/IWP5IhKaLZazAWxgrc6EPvcbQFgzU/T5EbHI
>   dt279SgTgQ+OlotfvnKNmL0CAwEAAQ== -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

And private key:

> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEA1ufdaaaDQuWPuBlw8VceWeGwdL3KhrC/YzgWi8oP72bQ2Zzg
>   xzNcXHdmWGfXax4EBlWwIPBbTSNboi6uriebbPNIS/ei/AjGBKO/yJ2iDkfnxmy6
>   xBxwpunqeq2TjEDDNXb2Y0g896gIjfwN8FZkolLspoFks5ipAxdYLNlWR5stgxWe
>   EXC2gpAPLaP00d3Xg/Qhsm2fUBvlJHQReiS1Mwyajg0EV72U3YpP0OK19z0YLBFR
>   haUbnE+Mx6TSnB9XqaWe4GKsBNSO06Lz4N9jk7Sg16DXpueKHo8pDZwuN2qbIG3f
>   Gc3ibNMR2U6lux218BGTIgGdvoAar1E3cOF1VmLI3aDS/EVejzDs3gkG1rxcrbCF
>   ajnWe5Yl1J+nXefFBedr2FLx6ChSPZFV1x3PDUmR1hb/NDsLHwnj7qQqqhtgfPdF
>   ql4EjGFGUvYgid1K0u/8B6Vqk0k9JKU5nrN5d1e3H7qJm/kbBoHNsI/0gbuUyRKT
>   IpxU5b9ex51WpA80FBMC/Ao6DeWLNu59W134YGu5kfI1qFI0w5xUsA3IU91Ak2tH
>   YEzzjnIz0rVMoJezLbtxcv26e5gMDjuQN//dUM/Qe6Akck382yYgdrivgUjxB3A/
>   IWP5IhKaLZazAWxgrc6EPvcbQFgzU/T5EbHIdt279SgTgQ+OlotfvnKNmL0CAwEA
>   AQKCAgBzYwMq2tDXdlJ4UpClxFTzhY4s4EqBjxzztQXGALQVomq4rNazngwVSbaV
>   +Qtc5Dzc+d0bknIzNKzao53+vB1jnixPPaMxF7TagOFUYe7FJC56B58v9OU3eZkA TXpPb+ZgKoOYQw0ZHAub0J3bUUevMD8IF6luFKWKl1osmnUM9XC2VUENtCsKZzb/
>   Fm040ZgJrWb6WomThaa+r+NCZbs0sau6YZrXUV9ApCa+zTtOiGsWHiZbT49Hmh7I
>   guLiGKIE4HwxlkkuPsKBN5kiQE9C21UQ8bdYUjGCvvMX76eQ8ZhhDR0gyb6tF5cZ
>   ynSJxyYMxCLvu1ZrFnU9dKoD3coVn0lBeWZH17zVkGWIV6XmQ4aSM2wB2Qobvv0T
>   U8M/R1dqObCxCycJEB0LHhB4bAC98g5W2B8hL46ENn/YnUqxzLzWucVfwI/e59N2
>   kJm5FxHrE4empTT/Zfyn+/A36vDEHafb4yHDX2gQTHW7US47DaXMbkKME37oBqAz
>   oy2p1XNMAWq+yg/XznloHBZ5HQ3nThG4kD93AnXNCKVUYc0gy8ROqEwoFYWAGs9a
>   ircv4SwCVDm2LM1uYMB95L39yg5i038ndW0sfDn8FBw4YIik//+KezHL/1Yr0fRF
>   0gPFYcLtXFLYqbsPqg1wq7VOCtZ1+NhgzsAgWDULfFJhViFzAQKCAQEA/YMAJgqs
>   QLzNMAwpvCXqU1JShf9B3qc0J8LHO1mdy1qCCh873aFVJNppgX7j6PvXkuOotRWE
>   /Em+0dyqJxrd8B1ifEA3MbON3WGEYZR5BIgBvxW9vFlbKzKhOwjWBX9zIVok2WMg
>   TPoMPAxs0x0fJGKzBkVvg5pjolyLdhIr1j79nn8z7EIgoJ2ZhQiOZPBmGR/MIt1Y
>   dBroWa/8cSEy4SLqfifsoqx8AaN9lQwJXJck2/bZ2Ft47jtXOxhL2NfqY3eMvRlt
>   nPwC1hTTbGw1zFvqGTEK76W9zdD+nwkrC38lLDH01dBcDeRbJ8NbwfSVbH4d1Y+Z
>   wbG3ygUozOisLQKCAQEA2QPb44wYCuI06eUI8i8h8gqEpj6lzWBss4259CFg7rVK
>   9tuQS5VlazJ8l11+gjIX7E+mtwwo1oSzyf9qsIvNgwLS2CwdIxCn+Ldka4NLTfUP
>   BQ3KtFbS8O8z0dijdzulTAOv+zZw9GtcisvjVaN3sIlJQ91LkfDfQQE6pQgi4E7a
>   ajjf6mloDtInbSId0X2DcirokjQ0CH65QLScvrgL8DwU6kAhGAjQQxy79AkbDhdh
>   1R5jq2IhUdoJdvBSwvieT+46XsZxX3He0ObZ086eVQBcuxoGYesSQvsfQ/RIH1f7
>   AXrKbnDbsookpfA7+WXuivMZICn9EbOFJNYEqboo0QKCAQEA4bX3NeeewezXi4Xo
>   yrm/TfwnuWIxVXntN9F17WO22E13Jmf0tzljQ3KrKT6+0LsZjpDfrorAYpeOK++a
>   F0MWgyjGfPX3rmq9TnP6l57HuL8XPviue7nbMDTd1F/jnfWBnhpSYLKfGaovpm8x
>   nS16grzVxCmiRbv6JZ7cFH3NRe3DhZCfvCSMRDTNcOLTVQ+s94WWDRyiGo2yfdfw
>   nRD/6e9adIQ7bgLATf0wXLngw+1WRfocr0OSAhoXamgRb7md2H2icuLm8zR1mgHk
>   083sgEz9uvwtTn105oDDkvlot822XQkFgjEHJN9CQb7wPVn0iCopifFW5lvC1T2O
>   vBIU6QKCAQEAziF2OZsWMzBOJmSgrLnMOoV3Hhmfj4apeZuDJ7qUweh9/iDr3H9Z
>   SAs6gOQTiENgqdu2dWQdXjXKOHJdurfwSyLhduff/TCS/BHmVqDtZG0DCT/ibI2T
>   67qptAdcraKADcXq4GkDvYZE7qlflDajN5IPf2CxqTvsM2ihdaRWzEzZ9c90EMpy
>   RrGjNWwUeqoHsufC5Sykx/TmrelggV98J4JKM38acCPe/gBLHy+O/UGEcdRdw6qA
>   D6lVGB6J3hwc87tKwj8n7QrSJAdCnIdDqWWgry+3JEcOn4S8W+Wqo+sDxpIFugWF
>   CP9idCPOM8R4Yo8qLHz1nlyweR64ayciIQKCAQAuWLYvCBWJ5RjsG+m6RSisf/QS
>   uoPN+D1midgGrBBUC6NSSPusr8ACBWgPng4wJiR9uRgpN1FMpo/SKKyiIwFieWKu
>   m/kKPWkfZjVpwA84kSY7yx4LtQlRIDdF2+nTtLhYr4NfJ3i3yFMOPASkv2hx3X4D
>   2tlTmrR+Ug9fhS6O2YpjQVJDBLm21R98oT1BWKI7+X2hx6c8AQ25t5+9M6Kf6vtv
>   WHvk3ws6P9mHnHeGPufA+iP782mrNM5wnrj6qt1aMldV1g4c+oQW1kr29o9A0N37
>   qZnIn3kCiMldMyQlk0ITJ34Tt60dvpElF1Jh0JurfQI9IAGOCCP7Ciz4rZX5 -----END
>   RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

So I save these two files to my server where I am storing my keys.  When my app runs, it receives the appropriate public/private keys just like this, in this format, in text format.  Here is my question:  How do I use these existing keys, based upon the algorithm (SHA512, 4096 bits) in a function to both encrypt and decrypt `NSString`s?  To my understanding, I have to do some work with the keys before I can use them with iOS - strip headers, convert to base64, eg?

In short, I am looking to create two functions.  One that can decrypt and one that can decrypt - both should take the certificates in text format above (or converted to something else) as well as the text to be encrypted and return the encrypted/decrypted version.

Comment: I would discourage the direct use of openssl. It is very low level and requires a lot of cryptographic background to apply correctly. What is your usage scenario? If want to securely communicate between an iphone and your server, then a TLS/SSL encrypted connection, probably in the form of an HTTPS connection, is likely the best approach. There are many online guides to set up Apache or nginx with TLS/SSL.

Comment: The end goal is to store encrypted text on a remote server.  It must be able to be decrypted later as well.  I have the mechanism for generating/storing keys just not the actual encrypt and decrypt.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using SHA512 for the encryption/decryption, that value is used if you are then going to create a certificate or certificate request tied to this keypair.

Here is a breakdown on the parameters you used:

```
"digest_alg" => "sha512"
```

For the digest in a certificate.

```
"private_key_bits" => 4096,
"private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
```

This means you generated an RSA-4096 key pair.  So make sure to encrypt/decrypt using RSA-4096.

Answer (score 1):

While this library doesn't address my original needs, it's security is more than enough for my requirements.  It easily adds encrypting/decrypting across multiple languages as well.

https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor